# unable to set and retrieve session variables

Tags: python-2.7, django-views, session-cookies, django-1.10

Using Django 1.10

My middleware is set as follows:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',

'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',


'wagtail.wagtailcore.middleware.SiteMiddleware',
'wagtail.wagtailredirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
]
```

I made sure to include the SESSION ENGINE

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies'
```

I have my client secret and id set as follows:

```
os.environ['CLIENT_SECRET'] = 'something'
os.environ['CLIENT_ID'] = 'something'
```

and my views are setup to do a callback, store session variables as follows:

```
def potato_oauth_callback(request):


  POTATO_OAUTH2_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = "https://login.potato.com/potatoservices/potatooauth2/potatotoken"
  POTATO_SECRET = get from env variables
  POTATO_ID = get from env variables
  POTATO_TYPE = "authorization_code"
  POTATOCALLBACK_URL = "https://potatourl/potatoes/potatocallback"

  authorization_code = request.GET.get('code')

  payload = {
    'potato_type': POTATO_TYPE,
    'potato_id': POTATO_ID,
    'potato_secret': POTATO_SECRET,
    'potato_uri': POTATOCALLBACK_URL,
    'code': potato_code
  }

  r = requests.post(POTATO_OAUTH2_TOKEN_ENDPOINT, data=potatoload)

  resp = r.json()

  potatoAccess = {
    'id': resp['id'],
    'timestamp': resp['issued_at'],
    'instanceURL': resp['instance_url'],
    'signature': resp['signature'],
    'accessToken': resp['access_token']
  }

  request.session['potatoAccess_id'] = potatoAccess['id']
  request.session['potatoAccess_timestamp'] = potatoAccess['timestamp']
  request.session['potatoAccess_instanceURL'] = potatoAccess['instanceURL']
  request.session['potatoAccess_signature'] = potatoAccess['signature']
  request.session['potatoAccess_accessToken'] = potatoAccess['accessToken']

  return HttpResponse(t.render({}, request))
```

Subsequently, when I do a request to recheck my session variables, I keep getting Key Errors and am unable to retrieve them:

```
def check_potatoes(request):
  c = {}
  c['potatoAccess_id'] = request.session['potatoAccess_id']
  print request.session['potatoAccess_id']
  return HttpResponse(json.dumps('potatoes'), content_type='application/json')
```

OR

```
def check_potatoes(request):
  try:
    c = {}
    c['potatoAccess_id'] = request.session['potatoAccess_id']
    print request.session['potatoAccess_id']
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps('potatoes'), content_type='application/json')
  except Exception as potatoes:
    potatoesdata = {'message': potatoes.message}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(potatoesdata), content_type='application/json')
```

To be noted, when I do the initial callback, I can validate that:

```
request.session['potatoAccess_id'] returns a value
potatoAccess['id'] returns a value
```

when changing views (other method called via ajax)
I get these keyErrors as if the values never existed

Answer (score 0):

Beginners mistake - 
the callback was being sent using a tunneling service ngrok.io for those of you not familiar with it, (so I could actually have a secure connection) and the rest of the session I was simply doing it on my localhost, so my setup is correct, I was just not in the same session, hence why my variables were non existent...

My 'login' was being done at https://localhost:8000/login,
however, the callback was being done over ngrok towards 
"https://login.potato.com/potatoservices/potatooauth2/potatotoken"

and I continued testing over my localhost, when the session variables are available from https://xxx.ngrok.io/potatourls